# 24V signal to drive led

Tags: led, opto-isolator, plc

I have a PLC which gives 24V DC output. I would like to drive an external LED using 24V.

Is this the correct way to drive an led?
Which is the right method let me know any changes needed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOEO4h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Your title says 24 V but your text says 12 V. Could you edit to clarify?

Comment: Also, how big an LED are you talking about? A 5 mA indicator, or a 100 W lamp?

Comment: i wanna blink normal 3mm LED external. usually PLC has inbuilt LED for notification. but i would like to blink external 3mm led separately.

Comment: cct1 is bad - it shorts the power supply in order to extinguish. This only works if Imax_supply is less than I_out_psu_max. If you MUST reverse signal polarity in this manner place the opto across the LED. | Circuit 2 needs a single series resistor - R = V/I = (24V-Vf_Led)/Vseries. Vf LED is about 3V for white LEDs. less for some others - see spec sheets.

Answer (score 3):

Really all you need is a single series resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f52Iaf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. OP's thoughts.*

In your first circuit the LED will light while the PLC output is off. If the opto-isolator turns on then it will try to short-circuit the 5 V supply to ground. That would destroy the opto-isolator if enough current flows through it. As it turns R1 will limit the current through the opto-LED to \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {24}{10k} = 2.4 \ \text {mA} \$ so the opto-transistor may not turn on hard enough. I have written a little on "current transfer ratio" in [Opto-isolators intro](http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-isolators/).

In your second circuit R4 is just wasting power and should be removed from the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCwY4C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. All that is required for 5 mA through the LED.*

The power dissipated in R1 is given by \$ P = \frac {V^2}{R} = \frac {24^2}{4700} = 122 \ \text {mW} \$ so a 0.25 W resistor would be fine.